# Drawn circles are larger then Bitmaps of equal size in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

So I'm drawing a circle with the following code

```java
public void drawCircle(int radius, ImageView imageView)
{
    Paint circlePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius*2, radius*2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas circleCanvas = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
    circleCanvas.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, circlePaint);
    //canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); used on the picture to the right
    imageView.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
}
```

This will draw the following circles on my screen
[image: circle with bitmap.width == radius*2] [image: circle with bitmap.width == radius*2 on white background]

As you might see the top, bottom, left and right parts of the circle are slightly cut off. Setting the background color of the bitmap to white shows the culprit. The drawn circle, which as the same radius as the bitmap's width and height, is slightly larger than the bitmap.

To make sure this was what was going on I tried drawing the same sized circle but I increased the size of the bitmap by about 5% and centered the circle inside it. This gave me the following:

[image: circle with bitmap.width = radius*2*1.05] [image: circle with bitmap.width == radius*2*1.05 on white background]

As you can probably see these circles do not have the same cutoff that the previous circles have.

Is this the expected behavior? If I want to draw proper circles of size x will I then always need to create bitmaps of size > x and then correctly center the circle inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out why this was happening. Quite simple actually.
Stroke is added to the outside of the circle's radius. So a circle with **Radius = 10px** and **Stroke = 2px** has a drawn radius of **12px** but is still considered a circle with a radius of 10px.

In this instance it can be fixed by simply setting the Paint properties as so:

```java
Paint circlePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
circlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
```